# Catch result of sub-process in Z-shell

Tags: shell, zsh, subshell

```
AAA <options>; CCC AAA <options>
```

`AAA`, `CCC` are different commands.

Here we're in an zsh script - for example:

```
vi script.zsh
<...>
AAA <options>; CCC AAA <options>
<...>
```

Verbose: Correct me if I'm wrong, `CCC AAA <options>`'s `AAA <options>` will be using a subshell and then create a separated process from current shell or may be using current shell and then create a sub-process from the process that running current script.

The problem is that `CCC` will stay alive after `script.zsh` is finished. This causes problem that when I try to call something that as result - not the return value (it did create something after done - a newly created object for i.e) of `CCC AAA <options>`'s `AAA <options>` **INSIDE** `script.zsh` causing `not found` warning.

That's being said, how to make current `script.zsh` can see the result of `'AAA <options>'`?

If possible target the Z-shell.

EDIT:
Should be:

```
AAA <options>; CCC AAA <options>
```

Comment: what result? standard out? err? both? the exit status code?

Answer (score 1):

No,

```
CCC 'AAA <options>'
```

Starts `CCC` with one literal `AAA <options>` argument. That's the same in every shell. You can verify by using the `echo` command in place of `CCC`:

```
$ echo 'AAA <options>'
AAA <options>
```

If you wanted to call `CCC` with the output (without the trailing newline characters) of `AAA` as one single argument, you'd do:

```
CCC "$(AAA <options>)"
```

If you wanted to call `CCC` with as many words as there are in the output of `AAA` (space, tab, newline, NUL separated), you'd do:

```
CCC $(AAA <options>)
```

In any case, `CCC` won't  be started until `AAA` has returned and the script won't terminate until `CCC` has returned.

For a script to terminate before a command returns, you'd need it to start that command asynchronously like with:

```
CCC args &
```

In any case, that's the same in every shell, it's not `zsh` specific (except for that splitting on NUL above).

Comment: I edited the 1st post, it's actually `AAA <options>; CCC AAA <options>`

Comment: I found out that I assumed that `CCC AAA <options>` had completed and `object` had been created but that's not true, I had to put while loop to test against the exsiting of the object and wait till it completely created before do other task so the question is why I put the command to process against `object` after the `CCC AAA <options>`, zsh shell did not wait till the process to complete to move to next command that make me conclude `AAA <options>` might run in a sub-process or a separated shell. Is that true?

Comment: @TuyenPham, not sure what you mean `AAA <options>` starts `AAA` with `<options>` as argument in a child process and `zsh` waits for the child process to return, `CCC AAA <options>` starts `CCC` with `AAA`, `<options>` as arguments and zsh waits for that process to return. Whether `CCC` treats its first argument as a command name is not known to `zsh`. `CCC` may itself fork child processes that keep running after their parent dies, but again zsh or any other shell would not know nor care about them.

Comment: True, zsh seems doesn't care, probably here `CCC` did a fork process to process `AAA <options>` and the `AAA <options>` took longer to process of `CCC `. That caused the problem.